# How to globally save data from the server?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Recently I started to practice Vue, and can't figure out how to organize a "global storage".

And now, to the point:

It is necessary to get user data once (from the server) in order to then work with them from any component.

For example, I need to get data in the components: left menu, top menu and page - these are already three requests, but I would like to limit myself to one :)

I tried vuex, but when used store in components, it makes another one request to the server:

userModule.js

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export const userModule = {
    state: () => ({
        current: {},
    }),

    getters: {
        getUser(state) { return state.current },
    },

    mutations: {
        setUser(state, user) { state.current = user },
    },

    actions: {
        async updateUser({state,  commit}) {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get('/office/api/me');
                commit('setUser', response.data);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
                alert('Error');
            }
        },
    },

    namespaced: true,
}
```

The code I use in components:

```js
import {mapState} from 'vuex';

export default {

  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("user/updateUser");
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      user: state => state.user.current,
    }),
  }
}
```

Comment: Vuex it's a full client-side solution - it cannot make requests to server out of the box. Please include some code.

Comment: @Daniel, but js can. I dont need help to make requests. I need help with async global storage.

Comment: In `created() { this.$store.dispatch("user/updateUser"); }` you are making `updateUser()` do the ajax request. If you call this in every `created()` of every component - yes that will query the API every time. You can call that once at the start of your application.

Comment: @PeterKrebs, that's why I'm asking how I can define a global, asynchronous variable once. Can you tell me?

Comment: Well I did. But sure let's go into detail. You should initialize VueX just one time. Depends how your Vue3 project is set up. You should have an `App.vue` where you can put your call in `create()`, but only there. `$store` should be available from other components with the user data, as soon as the user is loaded.

Comment: just add an `if` in your action . for ex `if !state.user.current.id` then do the request

Comment: @PeterKrebs, it works! Thanks a lot! As I thought - the solution was simple.
If you move your comment to the answer, I will mark it as solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Only use `updateUser` once

The error here is that every component will load the user, since every `created()` looks like:

```js
created() {
  this.$store.dispatch("user/updateUser");
}
```

You should initialize VueX just one time. Depends how your Vue3 project is set up.

You should have an `App.vue` where you can put your call in `create()`, but only there. Then `$store` should be available from other components with the user data, as soon as the user is loaded.